# storing callback with unknown type parameters in object

Tags: c++

I want to store a callback inside an object that will be invoked when asynchronous operation is finished.
The problem is that one of the arguments that will be passed to the callback will not be known until after the asynchronous operation. Here is the object that will store the callback:

```
    template<typename ... ResultColumnTypes>
    class PostgresCallerQueryResult : public PostgresCallerResult
    {
    public:
        PostgresCallerQueryResult(std::function<void(bool success, ozo::rows_of<ResultColumnTypes...> &results)> callback):
        m_results(std::make_shared<ozo::rows_of<ResultColumnTypes...>>()),
        m_callback(callback)
        {}
    ~PostgresCallerQueryResult(){}
    PostgresCallerQueryResult ( const PostgresCallerQueryResult & ) = delete;

    bool is_empty()
    {
        if (m_results == nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return (*m_results).empty();
    }
    ozo::rows_of<ResultColumnTypes...>& get_data()
    {   
        return (*m_results);
    }
    void callback()
    {
        m_callback(m_success, get_data());
    }
    
private:
    std::shared_ptr<ozo::rows_of<ResultColumnTypes...>> m_results;
    std::function<void(bool success, ozo::rows_of<ResultColumnTypes...> &results)> m_callback;
};
```

So the goal is to have the "m_callback" have 1 more parameter which is unknown at the creation of the object.

Here is how the callback is passed to the object:

```
int main()
{
   postgres_caller->query(std_func, "SELECT length FROM this_table WHERE id > $1 AND id < $2;", 11, 14);
}

template<typename... ResultColumnTypes, typename... ParameterTypes>
void PostgresCaller::query(std::function<void(bool success, ozo::rows_of<ResultColumnTypes...>& results)> callback, const std::string& query, ParameterTypes&& ... parameters)
{
    SVS_TRACE1 << "executing query";

    auto result = std::make_unique<PostgresCallerQueryResult<ResultColumnTypes...>>(callback);
    
    //start the asynchornous query
    ozo::request(m_connection_pool[AsyncEngine::instance()->get_io()],
                 ozo::make_query(query, std::forward<ParameterTypes>(parameters)...),
                 ozo::into(result->get_data()),
                 [m_self = shared_from_this(), result = std::move(result)](ozo::error_code ec, auto connection) mutable
                 {
                    m_self->query_result(std::move(ec), std::move(connection), std::move(result));
                 });        
}
```

When the asynchronous operation is finished query_result will be invoked with the "connection" as one of the parameters, it is this variable that i want to forward to the callback in the next step. Here is the query_result function:

```
template<typename ConnectionType, typename... ResultColumnTypes>
void PostgresCaller::query_result(ozo::error_code&& ec, ConnectionType&& connection, std::unique_ptr<PostgresCallerQueryResult<ResultColumnTypes...>> result)
{
    if(ec)
    {
        SVS_TRACE1 << "Postgres query failed. lifetime: " << result->time_alive() << " ms ";

        SVS_WARNING() << get_error_msg(ec, connection);
    }
    else
    {
        SVS_TRACE1 << "Postgres query succeeded. lifetime: " << result->time_alive() << " ms ";

        result->was_success();
    }
    result->callback();
}
```

My thought is to pass the "connection" variable to the result->callback(). Is this doable with std::function or am i required to use lambdas as the callback and have "auto connector" as one of the parameters?

Comment: what do you mean? i am using std::function already?

Comment: Does `connection` has base interface? How look like `std_func`?